# how to change element CSS position with animation

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I want to change an HTML element position from static to fixed at top 50% and left 50% of the browser window but the code just leads to background-color change!

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: static;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        background-color: red;
        position: static;
        top: auto;
        left: auto;
    }
    to {
      background-color: yellow;
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer via 'Vangel Tzo' help :

```
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes example {
    from {
        background-color: red;
    }
    to {
      background-color: yellow;
      transform: translate(50vw, 50vh);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: `You can't animate position.`

Instead of applying  `position: fixed` through keyframes try to add a class `fixed` or something via javascript.

An example: https://jsfiddle.net/6Ldqhoce/

Alternative you could move the element with `transform: translate` but it won't be fixed.

Comment: how set {transform: translate} by percentage for browser dimention ?

Comment: I haven't really tried to use it before with browser dimension but I suppose this might work `transform: translate(50vw, 50vh)`

Comment: ...and once element is where we want we can change `position` even without animation so nobody mentioned that!

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot** change `position` using `CSS-animation` because `position` is **NOT** an **animatable property**.

[List of animatable properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-properties).

However, **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/uUnA5/66/)** fiddle might help you.

Comment: @GeorgicaFaraFrica The fiddle is working for me.
It doesn't animate the `position` but it adds a class using Javascript which has different position.
You can see the difference by commenting `tagline.classList.add('show');` and running it again

Answer (score 0):

You can't change css position value with css animation.

You can do this with jQuery

example is with hover, you can do according to your choice.

**Jquery**

> With the use of "Css"

```
$(".div_name").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("position", "static");
    }, function(){
    $(this).css("position", "fixed");
});
```

> With the use of "Animate"

```
 $(".div_name").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({"position":"static"}, 1000);
        }, function(){
        $(this).animate({"position":"fixed"}, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: i khow how to do it with jQuery but i want use CSS.

Comment: Then, I can only say, currently we don't have option to do it with css.